# Python Futures Concurrent not working in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, concurrent.futures

I am using `Python Futures Concurrent` inside one of the method for getting the result in python, it is working fine when I tried it on individual file, but when I integrate it with `Flask` Api, the result is undefined, I debug and find out that the flask api is returning the result without even waiting to the futures to finish processing the result. How to stop it till the result is processed.

My Code of futures inside the function which is called by the flask api:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures_np1 = [executor.submit(self.get_test_score, data, param) for param in param_list]
    futures_np2 = [executor.submit(self.get_test_score, param, data) for param in param_list]


result1 = [f.result() for f in futures_np1]
result2 = [f.result() for f in futures_np2]
return self.get_average_score(result1, result2)
```

Can anyone give better alternative for multithreading to speed up the processing according to the given problem?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone looking for the answer. The problem arrises because I am passing multiple parameters to futures which is returning a list of result, that will work perfectly on plain python, but in flask it will not work, so to work it out you have to only submit one request at time by using loop. Example:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for param in param_list:
        futures_np1 = executor.submit(self.get_test_score, data, param)
        result1.append(futures_np1.result())
```